# How do I use an Angular directive to update an img src attribute upon this promise being updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Totally new to AngularJS and I'm just trying to do some simple image preloading but getting a bit lost in the 'Angular way' of doing things. I know I need to use a directive somehow but don't know how do do it cleanly. I have an 'ImgLoader' service that takes an array of image locations and returns a promise, which my controller responds to. I'm using an approach similar to the one [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm) except I want to display each image *as it loads*.

Here is my view:

```
<ul>

  <li data-project-id="{{ project.slug }}" ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <a href="/#/projects/{{project.slug}}">
      <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
        // repeater because thumbnail is in an array, even though there is only 1
        <img ng-repeat="thumb in project.thumbnail" some-sort-of-directive />

    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function($scope, projectsService, imgLoader) {

  function loadImages(data) {
    // project data, including title, etc 
    $scope.projects = data;
    // I just need the thumbs as an array for my imgLoader service
    $scope.thumbs = [];
    // sanitise the data
    data.filter(function(data) {
      // get first (and only) thumb from array
      return $scope.thumbs.push(data.thumbnail[0].url);
    });

    // load 'em up
    imgLoader.loadImages($scope.thumbs)
      .then(onAllImagesLoaded, onImageError, onImageLoaded);
  }

  function onImageLoaded(imgSrc) {
    // do something with directive here?
    console.log(imgSrc);
  }

  function onImageError() {
    console.log('onImageError');
  }

  function onAllImagesLoaded() {
    console.log('onAllImagesLoaded');
  }

  projectsService.getProjects()
    .then(loadImages);

});
```

Basically, because I have to push the thumbnail data into an array for my imgLoader service, I'm not sure how to write a directive here as the relationship between the original model (some JSON pulled out of a CMS) and the thumbnail array I feed my imgLoader service is lost.

If I just wanted to hack something together I would probably use a lookup or something to match the data back up again but I'm sure something clever with directives could happen? Note, I want to pre-render the  tag and only show it/add a class when the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
.directive('spinnerOnLoad', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope,element){
                    element.on('load', function() {
                       //is loaded
                    });
                    scope.$watch('ngSrc', function() {
                       // loading
                    });      
                }
            }
        });
```

my is like:

```
.spinner{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                background: #CCC url(./spinner.gif) no-repeat center center;
                display: block;
                width:220px;
                height: 220px;
            }
            .feed img.spinner-show{
                visibility: visible;
            }
            .feed img.spinner-hide{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
    .directive('spinnerOnLoad', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function(scope,element){
                        element.on('load', function() {
                            element.removeClass('spinner-hide');
                            element.addClass('spinner-show');
                            element.parent().find('span').remove();
                        });
                        scope.$watch('ngSrc', function() {
                            element.addClass('spinner-hide');
                            element.parent().append('<span class="spinner"></span>');
                        });      
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like this is bypassing my service though? I would prefer to react to the promise than adding another load event handler. Would totally work though :)